# How do I conditionally sum cells in excel?

Tags: excel-formula

Here is a table that I'm working with (an ascii art representation fo it):

```
|---|---------|-----------|--
|   |A        |B          |
|---|---------------------|--
|1  |price    |override   |
|---|---------|-----------|--
|2  |10       |           |
|---|---------|-----------|--
|3  |20       |100        |
|---|---------|-----------|--
|4  |30       |           |
|---|---------|-----------|--
|5  |40       |90         |
|---|---------|-----------|--
|6  |50       |           |
|---|---------|-----------|--
|7  |150      |280        | <-- SUMS
|---|---------|-----------|--
|   |         |           |
```

column A has some prices, column B has an override price, if any.
Rows 1 to 6 have the prices, and row 7 has sums.

Row 7 is calculated as "=SUM(A1:A7)"

I want to write a formula for cell B7 that will do the following:

```
for every cell in range A1:A7
    if the override field for that price is blank
        add the original price to the total
    else
        add the override price to the total
```

**My question: what formula will do the above?**

I've looked at IF (cant figure out how to apply it on a range) and SUMIF(can't figure out how to get the "current cell" and "relative cell"), but I can't think of a way to do this. I'm a total novice at excel formulae.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

How about trying an array formula? In cell `B7`, try adding this:

```
=SUM(IF(ISBLANK(B2:B7), A2:A7, B2:B7))
```

And then pressing `Ctrl+Shift+Enter` to enter as an array formula. This will check if there is a value in column B and use it in the sum; otherwise, it will use the value in column A.

Comment: the "array formula" was the key - I did not know that there was anything called "array formula" in excel

Comment: It's super useful - one of those things that can be tricky to grasp at first but has a lot of situations where it can make things easy (like here :) ).

Answer (score 0):

It seems like the easiest is to create the third column, which cells you populate either with price or override by `=IF(ISBLANK(B1); A1; B1)` formula. Then you mouse drag the formula onto all cells (will update it accordingly). And then you just sum values in your third column.
Sorry, not an excel artist

Comment: haha - the simplest solution, but I will go any lengths to avoid that extra column. I'm looking for a solution that is beautiful and elegant :)

Comment: "Beautiful excel" sounds like a name for a very thick and expensive book :)

Answer (score 0):

I would have a new row.row C to collect the price needed to sum.

row C is like this

```
if(B1 = "",A1,B1)
```

you will have row C

```
C

10
100
30
90
50
```

then sum up this row C.you'll get what you want.