# how to use category to update all sheets

Tags: excel, excel-formula, vba

hi i need help figuring out a formula for a project im doing.

This is my scenario.

I have three spreadsheets

1st sheet is January
2nd sheet is February

3rd sheet is my total of the year

on 1st sheet i have the following tabs:

A|BCD|E|F|G|H

Date|Description|Category|Quantity|Price|Total

11/18/13|Invisible tape|Office|1|1.29|$1.29

11/18/13|water|water|1|0.75|0.75

11/18/13|paper|Office|1|5.85|$5.85

```
                        1.29|$1.29
```

and 2nd sheet ( is the same as 1st Sheet)

3rd Sheet is as follows

A|B

Expense|August

Equipment|$0.00

Prizes|$0.00

Printing|$0.00

Website|$0.00

Promotion|$0.00

Ice|$0.00

Office|$0.00

Food|$0.00

Gas|$0.00

Water|$0.00

Rental|$0.00

Total|$0.00

ok my question is how to click category select Office from a drop menu then automatically on 3rd sheet it updates the expense in august under category office.

ok i hope you can understand thanks

> > > > > > check video out <<<<<<<<<<< click on the link below were it says original video

[Original Video](http://tinypic.com/player.php?v=2r7yi60&s=8) - More videos at [TinyPic](http://tinypic.com)

[URL=http://tinypic.com/r/2r7yi60/8]View My Video[/URL]

Comment: If I am correct in thinking each month is its own sheet named after the months in your drop down, You will need the indirect function combined with a sum if for each category

Comment: is there any way i can get explained a little more on how to go about that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure I quite understand your question, but it seems like you would need something like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11946975/how-do-i-conditionally-sum-cells-in-excel).
You could use a formula like this in the total cells in the third sheet and they would update automatically.
It might look something like this for the Equipment row:

```
=SUM(IF(August!$E:$E=$A2, August!$H:$H, 0))
```

If you paste this in Sheet3 Cell B2 it should work.  It can then be copied to the other rows and it will change to "...=$A3...", "...=$A4..." and so on.

Don't forget to use Ctrl+Shift+Enter to set it as an array formula.

Addendum:
Correct me if I'm wrong, but It seems your goal is to get some kind of expense tracking workbook.  I'm going assume you have a sheet for each month of the year, not just January and February and also assume a column in the last sheet for each of the the months, not just August. If this is the case, then the formula can be expanded to work for every month by using the month name at the top of each column.  That would look something like this:

```
=SUM(IF(INDIRECT("'"&B$1&"'!$E:$E")=$A2, INDIRECT("'"&B$1&"'!$H:$H"), 0))
```

Comment: ok i can see were your going with it but i can't seem to get it to work thanks for you help

Comment: What part is not working?  Would a better explanation of the parts of the formula help?

Comment: the whole thing im gonna try to do a quick video to show you

Comment: I guess that was a bad question.  Is there a certain error being produced, or are the cells blank? A video (or maybe a copy of the spreadsheet) would definitely help me understand what needs done.

Comment: na no bad questions its me im a little slow to catch on im about to upload the video

Comment: Hey Zacru check this video out

Comment: click on the link above in the first question

Comment: Okay, after looking at your spreadsheet I noticed a few things that need to be changed in the formula. Try putting this in Cell B3 on the year expense sheet and then pressing Ctrl+Shift+Enter to save it. Then drag the corner to M13 to copy the formula to the rest of the cells.
`=SUM(IF(INDIRECT("'"&B$2&"'!$E:$E")=$A3, INDIRECT("'"&B$2&"'!$H:$H"), 0))`

Comment: i also forgot to add im working on a mac hope its the same keys

Comment: when i put it in to cell B3 it says #REF!

Comment: Well It should be the same keys.  The only other option might be Cmd+Shit+Enter.  If it's a vector formula it will be displayed with curly braces around the whole thing in the formula bar at the top so mine looks like this: `{=SUM(IF(INDIRECT("'"&B$2&"'!$E:$E")=$A3, INDIRECT("'"&B$2&"'!$H:$H"), 0))}`.  Other than that I'm not sure what could be wrong because it works on my computer.

Comment: Oh, What are the sheet names?  They need to match the names of the months.  Rename them to "January", "February", etc.

Comment: yes that was the problem Boss awesome working good thanks a lot is there any way to donate to you something

Comment: No problem. Sorry that took so long. As for donations, that little green check mark is good enough.

Comment: awesome thanks your a blessing Goodnight be safe i have alot more questions but that would be an other day thanks